# $http get failed to pass param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I opened network tab and check the param, it's not there. I wonder what I've done wrong.

```
 $http.get('/app/getAllUser',
            params: {
                id: '123'
            }).then(function(response){

        }).catch(function(response) {
            alert('Error!');
        }).finally(function(){
            $scope.loading = false;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your route looks like, you can put the id right in the url.  '/app/getAllUser/123'

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the second parameter in an object:

```
$http.get('/app/getAllUser', {
    params: {
        id: '123'
    }
}).then(function(response){
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are passing your parameter, below is one sample:

```
 function getAuthorByID(authorId) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/Author/' + authorId
        })
        .then(sendResponseData)
        .catch(sendGetAuthorsError);
    }
```